# How to change location while using Monkey while testing app?

Tags: android, automated-tests, monkey

How to test with different location as I am using latitude and longitude functionality in my app?

My code for monkey is
`monkey -s 1009 1000000 --throttle 10000 --pct-syskeys 0 --ignore-crashes --ignore-security-exceptions --ignore-timeouts`

I have to run my app continuously for a long time to collect more data, so i want to automate the change in location. I cant use Emulator to do the testing as I have changed the binaries of my mobile software.

Comment: Use Mock Location in Real Device . I . Emulator use GPS Data Palyback in Emulator Control'

Comment: @TominB  I have to run my app continuously for a long time to collect more data, so i want to automate the change in location. I cant use Emulator to do the testing as I have changed the binaries of my mobile software.

Comment: Use this app for fake GPS location https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.gavrikov.mocklocations&hl=en

Comment: @ss_ Thanks , but i wanted an option through monkey(if there is one) where the change in location is based on the seed value you give.